# Spring container - annotation for null argument

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

In my application that uses Spring container I created my own annotation, and I wanted at runtime get Class objects of classes that are annotated with my annotation. For this I wanted to utilize Spring container.

In my .xml configuration file I put

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.package" >
   <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="some.package.Question" />
</context:component-scan>
```

so the classes that are annotated with my Question annotation are detected by Spring. Problem is that those classes don't have no parameter constructor, so now I have 2 options:

1. Define no-parameter constructor in those classes
2. Define the beans in .xml and use constructor-arg

but is it possible to annotate constructor arguments with some annotation, so Spring will know that it needs to pass `null` value during creation of a bean?

Also those beans will have prototype scope, and from the point of view of an application the contents of an constructor arguments are not known during the creation of a bean.

EDIT:
I had to use `@Value("#{null}")` for annotation constructor arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first suggestion of using a no-arg constructor sounds cleaner - the reason is that the object created is, from your perspective, being considered properly initialized even though the instance variables have null values  - this can be indicated by having a default constructor

If it cannot be changed, your approach of using @Value("#{null}") also works, I was able to test out in a test case:

```
@MyAnnotation
public class Component1 {
    private String message;

    @Autowired
    public Component1(@Value("#{null}") String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String sayHello(){
        return this.message;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you're looking for, but if you want to re-use Spring's classpath scanner and wrap it in your own implementation, you can use the following;

```
Class annotation = [your class here ];
String offsetPath = [your path here ];

// Scan a classpath for a given annotation class
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);

// MZ: Supply the include filter, to filter on an annotation class
scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(annotation));

for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(offsetPath))
{
    String name = bd.getBeanClassName();
    try
    {
        Class classWithAnnotation = Class.forName(name);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Logger.fatal("Unable to build sessionfactory, loading of class failed: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
```